# 'invalid_request', error_description: 'AADB2C90055: The scope 'openid profile' provided in request must specify a resource,

Tags: oauth

I'm trying to autheticate using Oauth service provided by my client and I get this error.

'invalid_request', error_description: 'AADB2C90055: The scope 'openid profile' provided in request must specify a resource, such as 'https://example.com/calendar.read'.

The scope I use is "openid"
Response type I use is "code id_token token"

I'm expecting it to authenticate and send me back the token.